# Python list management question (specific example)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm writing a program that will print a table on a pdf page, but in order to do that the table needs to be rearranged. I would like to write a function that would rearrange and modify a list. This is a sample input list:

```
sample_list = [
    ["Item1 ", 5, 5],
    ["Item2 ", 2, 8],
    ["Item3 ", 3, 7],
    ["Item4 ", 3, 2],
    ["Item5 ", 2, 8],
    ["Item6 ", 4, 9],
    ["Item7 ", 1, 4],
    ["Item8 ", 4, 2],
    ["Item9 ", 7, 2],
]
```

The function I want to create would accept `sample_list` variable as a parameter and return rearranged list which would look like this:

```
sample_list = [
    [["ITEM NAME ", "QTY", "PRICE PER UNIT", "TOTAL"],
     ["Item1 ", 5, 5, 25],
     ["Item2 ", 2, 8, 16],
     ["Item3 ", 3, 7, 21]],

    [["Item4 ", 3, 2, 6],
     ["Item5 ", 2, 8, 16],
     ["Item6 ", 4, 9, 36],
     ["Item7 ", 1, 4, 4],
     ],

    [["Item8 ", 4, 2, 8],
     ["Item9 ", 7, 2, 14],
     ["TOTAL", "", "", 146]],
]
```

1. It would multiply QTY over PRICE PER UNIT and store it as TOTAL in every sub-list
2. It would insert ["ITEM NAME ", "QTY", "PRICE PER UNIT", "TOTAL"] list in the beginning (as shown)
3. It would split sub-lists into blocks of max 4 items per block
4. It would add ["TOTAL", "", "", 146] in the end

Basically, if we have `sample_list[x][y]`

x is an index of the block,
y is the index of the item

`sample_list` could be a list of any size, therefore function should be able to handle it and the number of blocks in the output list can vary, but the number of items in each block can not exceed 4, with the exception of the last block - it could have 5 items if necessary

When I try to write a function like this it becomes too messy and I get lost in endless for loops.

Comment: Does the header only exist in the first chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
def modify(s_list):
    """
        Arg    : `s_list` -> List
        Returns: `s_list` -> List

        1) Using list comprehension the
           'TOTAL' of every sub-list is 
           found.
           
        2) The final 'TOTAL' from the 
           'TOTAL' is calculated using 
           `sum()`.
           
        3) The 'label list' is inserted at 
           the beginning of the `s_list`.
           
        4) The `s_list` is divided grouping
           items in four.
           
        5) The 'total list' containing the 
           final 'TOTAL' is inserted at the 
           end of the `s_list`.
           
        6) The modified `s_list` is returned.
    """
    
    s_list = [
        l + [l[1] * l[2]]
        for l in s_list
    ]
    total = sum(l[3] for l in s_list)
    s_list.insert(0, [
        'ITEM NAME ', 'QTY', 
        'PRICE PER UNIT', 'TOTAL'
    ])
    s_list = [
        s_list[i:i + 4] 
        for i in range(0, len(s_list), 4)
    ]
    s_list.append([
        'TOTAL', '', '', total
    ])
    
    return s_list
    
    

sample_list = [
    ["Item1 ", 5, 5],
    ["Item2 ", 2, 8],
    ["Item3 ", 3, 7],
    ["Item4 ", 3, 2],
    ["Item5 ", 2, 8],
    ["Item6 ", 4, 9],
    ["Item7 ", 1, 4],
    ["Item8 ", 4, 2],
    ["Item9 ", 7, 2]
]

print(modify(sample_list))

# Output
#
# [
#   [
#     ['ITEM NAME ', 'QTY', 'PRICE PER UNIT', 'TOTAL'], 
#     ['Item1 ', 5, 5, 25], 
#     ['Item2 ', 2, 8, 16], 
#     ['Item3 ', 3, 7, 21]
#   ], 
# 
#   [
#     ['Item4 ', 3, 2, 6], 
#     ['Item5 ', 2, 8, 16], 
#     ['Item6 ', 4, 9, 36], 
#     ['Item7 ', 1, 4, 4]
#   ], 
# 
#   [
#     ['Item8 ', 4, 2, 8], 
#     ['Item9 ', 7, 2, 14], 
#     ['TOTAL', '', '', 146]
#   ]
# ]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Although I made a slight modification to it. As I mentioned in my post "the number of items in each block can not exceed 4, with the exception of the last block - it could have 5 items if necessary"

I simply put this piece of code:

s_list.append([
    'TOTAL', '', '', total
])

at the end of function and use s_list[-1] to indicate that I want it at the end of the list

Comment: @SebastianMeckovski updated. Just rearranged the order of 4 and 5 (see the function's docstring).

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and it works exactly the way I intended, thanks. My code was twice as long and not efficient so this is a lot better.

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept it. :)

Comment: sorry I'm new here. How do I do that? :D

Comment: Here we go I accepted, sorry for the delay. Your answer really helped me